# changing Python object in C++ by reference

Tags: python, c++, pointers, pass-by-reference, boost-python

The problem is following. 
Say, I have a class `Matrix` that is exposed to Python via **Boost.Python**. 
Now, here is another class `Calcs`:

```
class Calcs
{
public:
    Matrix* x;
    Matrix* res;

    Calcs(){ x = NULL; res = NULL; }

    void set_x(Matrix& x_){ x = &x_; }
    void set_res(Matrix& res_){ res = &res_; }

    void run_calc(){ *res = *x; }
    Matrix get_res(){ return *res; }
};
```

The Python usage would be:

```
x = Matrix(2,2)  # this will allocate memory for the matrix x
y = Matrix(2,2)  # same for y

c = Calcs() 
c.set_x(x)     # so now the internal pointer of the c object points to the 
               # location of the object x
c.set_res(y)   # same for y
c.run_calc()   # so now, we should be able to look at the object y and find 
               # the result stored in it, but it reality this object 
               # is not actually changed
c.get_res()    # this will give the answer as expected
```

As the comments of the Python script suggest, the usage pattern would be to allocate memory in the external objects (input and result), then make the pointers in the `Calcs` object to point to these locations, run calculations, and then have the results ready in `y`. But somehow this doesn't work and I have hard time understanding why.

On the good side, whenever I update the input matrix `x` and return the result using the function `get_res()`, the result is updated every time, accordingly to the value of `x`.

Still, the matrix `y` doesn't change its content. I'm thinking that Python might be creating some intermediate object, so when I update y in the C++, only that intermediate object *sees* the change and that's why the object `y` doesn't get updated.

So, I wonder if this is a correct understanding and how I could fix this problem.